# setting up Ubuntu 10.10 as paravirtualized guest in Xen on RHEL5 host - what kernel?

Tags: ubuntu, xen, rhel5

I've discovered the tool `ubuntu-vm-builder`, which I've installed and then invoked on an Ubuntu workstation as:

```
sudo vmbuilder xen ubuntu --suite maverick --flavour virtual --arch amd64 --mem=512 --rootsize 8192
```

This workstation is not the intended target host of the virtual machine, however; I would like to host the guest on a Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 machine that is running Xen 3.0.3.

The output of this command appears to be a folder named `ubuntu-xen` containing three files:

- `tmpXXXXXX`, a very large file which I assume is the root partition image
- `tmpYYYYYY`, a somewhat large file which I assume is the swap partition image
- `xen.conf`, a text file

I have copied the `xen.conf` file to the RHEL server's `/etc/xen` directory under the new name `newvm`, adjusting the paths of `tempXXXXXX` and `tempYYYYYY`in the file after also copying them from my local workstation to the RHEL server.  When I launch the Virtual Machine Manager `virt-manager`, I can see the `newvm` virtual machine listed underneath the Dom0 machine.

When I try to start `newvm`, I get the error:

```
Error starting domain: virDomainCreate() failed POST operation failed: (xend.err 'Error creating domain: Kernel image does not exist: None')
```

Indeed, there exists an entry `kernel = 'None'` in the `xen.conf` file.  How do I find out what the path of the kernel should be?  Is this path supposed to be to a kernel stored on the local filesystem of the RHEL5 host, or is it supposed to be a path inside the guest image?

I see that the `vmbuilder` command provides for a `--xen-kernel` option, along with a `--xen-ramdisk` option, but I'm not sure what to use for either.

I think I should be able to get this to work, since Ubuntu is [said to be supported](http://www.ubuntu.com/products/whatisubuntu/serveredition/techspecs/whatsnew#xen) as a Xen guest, even though the [Xen 4.0.1 docs state](http://docs.vmd.citrix.com/XenServer/4.0.1/guest/guest.html#install_linux) support for only a limited set of distributions, Ubuntu excluded.

---

**Update 1**

When running `vmbuilder` on my local workstation, I did observe an output line saying:

```
Calling hook: install_kernel
```

and later, output lines saying:

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-23-virtual
[...]
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 2.6.35-23-virtual /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-23-virtual
```

So in the `xen.conf` file, I tried setting the lines:

```
kernel = '/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-23-virtual'
ramdisk = '/boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-23-virtual'
```

When trying to start the VM, I got an error similar to last time:

```
Error starting domain: virDomainCreate() failed POST operation failed: (xend.err 'Error creating domain: Kernel image does not exist: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-23-virtual')
```

This makes me think that the RHEL5 machine is looking for local files, rather than a file within the binary guest disk image.

After running `sudo updatedb` on my workstation, neither of those files were found.  If the `vmbuilder` tool had tried to install them, it must have failed.

---

**Update 2**

I was able to extract the kernel and initrd images from the guest disk binary by mounting it:

```
mkdir mnt_tmp
sudo mount ubuntu-xen/tmpXXXXXX mnt_tmp/ -o loop
cp mnt_tmp/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-23-virtual virtual_kernel_ubuntu
cp mnt_tmp/boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-23-virtual virtual_initrd_ubuntu
```

These two files I copied to the RHEL5 server, and edited the `xen.conf` file to point to them as `kernel` and `ramdisk`.

With this done, I could "run" the `newvm` virtual machine from within `virt-manager`, but was met with the message

```
Console Not Configured For Guest
```

when I double clicked the entry to open the Virtual Machine Console.  As suggested by a forum, I then added the line

```
vfb = [ 'type=vnc' ]
```

to the configuration file, recreated the virtual machine (a ~10 min process), and this time got the message:

```
Connecting to console for guest
```

This remained indefinitely; after selecting View -> Serial Console, I found a kernel panic:

```
[5442621.272173] Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill the idle task!
[5442621.272179] Pid: 0, comm: swapper Tainted: G      D     2.6.35-23-virtual #41-Ubuntu
[5442621.272184] Call Trace:
[5442621.272191]  [<ffffffff815a1b81>] panic+0x90/0x111
[5442621.272199]  [<ffffffff810652ee>] do_exit+0x3be/0x3f0
[5442621.272204]  [<ffffffff815a5e20>] oops_end+0xb0/0xf0
[5442621.272211]  [<ffffffff8100ddeb>] die+0x5b/0x90
[5442621.272216]  [<ffffffff815a56c4>] do_trap+0xc4/0x170
[5442621.272221]  [<ffffffff8100ba35>] do_invalid_op+0x95/0xb0
[5442621.272227]  [<ffffffff8130851c>] ? intel_idle+0xac/0x180
[5442621.272232]  [<ffffffff810072bf>] ? xen_restore_fl_direct_end+0x0/0x1
[5442621.272239]  [<ffffffff815a48fe>] ? _raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore+0x1e/0x30
[5442621.272247]  [<ffffffff8108dfb7>] ? tick_broadcast_oneshot_control+0xc7/0x120
[5442621.272253]  [<ffffffff8100ad5b>] invalid_op+0x1b/0x20
[5442621.272259]  [<ffffffff8130851c>] ? intel_idle+0xac/0x180
[5442621.272264]  [<ffffffff813084e0>] ? intel_idle+0x70/0x180
[5442621.272269]  [<ffffffff810072bf>] ? xen_restore_fl_direct_end+0x0/0x1
[5442621.272275]  [<ffffffff8148a147>] cpuidle_idle_call+0xa7/0x140
[5442621.272281]  [<ffffffff81008d93>] cpu_idle+0xb3/0x110
[5442621.272286]  [<ffffffff815873aa>] rest_init+0x8a/0x90
[5442621.272291]  [<ffffffff81b04c9d>] start_kernel+0x387/0x390
[5442621.272297]  [<ffffffff81b04341>] x86_64_start_reservations+0x12c/0x130
[5442621.272303]  [<ffffffff81b08002>] xen_start_kernel+0x55d/0x561
```

---

**Update 3**

I tried an `i386` architecture instead of `amd64`, but got the same kernel panic.

Also, it seems the Virtual Machine Manager pays attention to the format of the filename of the kernel; for the same kernel binary, I tried simply naming it `vmlinuz-virtual`, which threw out an error box about an invalid kernel.  When I named it `vmlinuz-2.6.35-23-virtual`, it did not throw the error, but it did still result in the kernel panic shortly thereafter.

Comment: I'm curious... any reason for not using Ubuntu 12.04 instead?

Comment: @pepoluan, because the question was asked in 2010?

Comment: @psusi drats! I must've been drunk to not notice the date... :-P

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into the [xen-tools](http://www.xen-tools.org/software/xen-tools/) package which if you specify `--pygrub` on the `xen-create-image` command it will embed the kernel/initrd within the guest disk image which may make it easier for you to transfer guest images between systems.

Answer (score 1):

you might want to consider upgrading your xen infrastructure, xen 3.x does have limitations to which guests it supports. Have a look at the following, http://www.redhat.com/resourcelibrary/articles/enterprise-linux-virtualization-support

Have you tried an older ubuntu version?

Answer (score 0):

You should use (have used?) the linux-image-virtual kernels provided by Ubuntu, and a newer Xen hypervisor (possibly with pygrub or similar).

But your question is old, nowadays you wouldn't use Ubuntu-10.10 and on newer ones you use the same kernel under Xen (both hvm and paravirt) and on bare metal.